# How to backup database used on multiple computers at the same time

Tags: vb.net, database-backups

Written a booking program (vb.net) running on several independent computers. 
Right now I leave the database (access ole.db database) on one of the computers (called master) 
and the other computers (called slaves) find the database file there. 
But what if the master computer goes down? 
The Master computer, doing backup in cloud (google drive),
but it requires you then download the file to another machine 
and call that computer master.
There must be a smarter way, but can not figure it out. 
Hoping for a little help here.

Kind Regards 
Jan

Comment: You're gonna have to post more info-- Such as what database engine are you using?  MSSQL, MySQL, MSAccess?  Are these window's PC's?  Are they part of a domain?

Comment: You build the "master" PC with a raid array so you can mirror your database file. If one of the disks in the raid array goes down you still have access to your full database because it was mirrored to another disk. If another component of your "master" PC breaks you are still toast.